# PHP PDO connection failure

Tags: php, mysql, insert, pdo

Hey, so I am new with PDO, and I cannot figure out why my data will not insert into my tables. Much appreciated!

```
<?php

include("class.php");

$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "db";
$dbuser     = "user";
$dbpass     = "pass";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = strtolower($_POST['email']);
$firstName = ucwords(strtolower($_POST['firstName']));
$lastName = ucwords(strtolower($_POST['lastName']));
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$hash = Secure::Encrypt($username, $password);

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,password,email,firstName,lastName,createDate) VALUES (:username,:password,:email,:firstName,:lastName,:date)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(
':username'=>$username,
':password'=>$hash,
':email'=>$email,
':firstName'=>$firstName,
':lastName'=>$lastName,
':date'=>$date));

?>
```

Comment: Your question title says that you're getting a connection failure, but your question body does not mention a specific problem.  Can you please provide more details, like the full and complete wording of any errors you're getting?

Comment: Wrap your PDO code with a `try` block, with a catch for `PDOException`. Then get the exception message and include it in the question.

Comment: This may not be relative to your issue, but I am surprised how many people don't do this as it helps save debug time, esp with PDO. I tend to always check my queries manually.
If you have control of the server, ie a dev box etc. you may want to turn on mysql logging. If your on linux, e.g., /etc/mysql/my.cnf look for the log section, uncomment that, restart mysql /etc/init.d/mysql restart .. then as root (sudo -i) do this: tail -f /var/log/mysql/mysql.log | grep INSERT 
Remember to turn off mysql.log after your done. This file gets huge fast.

Answer (score 4):

If all of your table's field names match, I have found that PDO will sometimes fail if one of your array variables are empty.

to find out if any errors are being thrown, add the following after your `new PDO` declaration (PDO error reporting is silent by default):

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Then add `try`/`catch` around each PDO activity as follows:

```
try {
    ..Code Here...
}catch (PDOException $err) {
    echo $err->getMessage();
}
```

***Final Code:***

```
<?php

include("class.php");

$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "db";
$dbuser     = "user";
$dbpass     = "pass";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = strtolower($_POST['email']);
$firstName = ucwords(strtolower($_POST['firstName']));
$lastName = ucwords(strtolower($_POST['lastName']));
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$hash = Secure::Encrypt($username, $password);

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,password,email,firstName,lastName,createDate) VALUES (:username,:password,:email,:firstName,:lastName,:date)";
try {    
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
 }catch (PDOException $err) {
    echo 'Prepare Failed: '.$err->getMessage();
 }
try {    
    $q->execute(array(
    ':username'=>$username,
    ':password'=>$hash,
    ':email'=>$email,
    ':firstName'=>$firstName,
    ':lastName'=>$lastName,
    ':date'=>$date));
 }catch (PDOException $err) {
    echo 'Execute Failed: '.$err->getMessage();
 }

?>
```

Then please update with any errors you receive :)